# Como criar uma Grouped List no Laravel 4 a partir de uma entidade com auto-relacionamento

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando criar uma `select box com \Form::select() (grouped list)` no Laravel 4 e tenho a seguinte entidade:

### Itens

```
id = id do item
nome = nome do item
pai = fk dessa mesma entidade
```

Já criei o model com hasMany e vejo que ele retorna em uma estrutura encadeada a entidade pai e seus filhos recursivamente.

Mas não consigo criar a select box que só aceita como parâmetro um array. Há no laravel alguma forma "prevista" de converter essa estrutura do Itens para um array no formato aceito pelo `\Form::select()` ?

Comment: Já tentou o lists()?

Comment: Também utilizo a criação através do método `lists('descricao','id')`

Answer (score 8):

Seguindo os padrões de desenvolvimento, faça assim:

No seu model **Item** crie o seguinte método:

```php
/**
 * getList method
 * Retorna a lista de itens
 *
 * @access public
 * @return Array
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 * @author rogersneves
 */
public static function getList($optional = true)
{
  if ($optional) {
    return array('' => 'Selecione (opcional)') + static::lists('nome', 'id');
  } else {
    return static::lists('nome', 'id');
  }
}
```

### No seu controller

```php
$items = Item::getList();
return View::make('sua_view')->with('items', $items);
```

**Explicando:**

- O parâmetro `$optional` deste método é apenas para definir se irá ter uma opção padrão (sem valor) no seu *Grouped List*, por exemplo: **Selecione um item**.
- Após isso só há uma checagem se ele foi informado ou não, caso contrário retorna apenas a lista de elementos

**Obs:**

Caso queria adicionar uma condição neste método, basta fazer o seguinte:

```php
return array('' => 'Selecione (opcional)') + static::where('status', 1)->lists('nome', 'id');
```

Ou, no meu caso:

```php
return array('' => 'Selecione (opcional)') + static::active()->lists('name', 'id');
```

Sendo `active()` um scope definido no model (isso é exemplo apenas, não aplicado ao seu caso, ou caso queria, altere o nome dos campos):

```php
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Scopes
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Escopos pré-definidos
|
*/
/**
 * scopeActive method
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Array $query
 * @return void
 */
public function scopeActive($query)
{
  return $query->where('active', 1)->orderBy('name');
}
```

Comment: Caso a resposta de alguém para sua dúvida tenha lhe ajudado, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido, clicando na seta abaixo da área de votação.

Comment: +1 está aí alguém que entende bem o Laravel :)

Answer (score 3):

Digamos que seu **model** que herda do Eloquent se chame **Itens**, então para recuperar todos os registros, você pode usar:

```java
Itens::all()
```

Isso retorna os dados, mas não resolve o problema, você poderia até tentar popular os dados com

```java
{{ Form::select('meucampo', Itens::all() )}}
```

Mas isso resultaria em um json no campo, o que podemos resolver com

```java
{{ Form::select('meucampo', Itens::all()->lists('nome', 'id')) }}
```

Veja, ao Form::select estou passando 2 parametros, o primeiro é o nome do campo no formulário, o segundo é a lista de valores.

`Itens::all()` retorna todos os itens do `Model`, e `lists` transforma em `array` associativo, com os campos que passar como parametro.

Não consegui entender com clareza a pergunta, mas acho que é isso.